# What tools exist for testing multithreaded .net code?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, unit-testing

Are there any tools that can help find race conditions when testing multi-threaded .net code? I'm looking for something with similar capabilities to IBM's [ConTest](http://www.alphaworks.ibm.com/tech/contest) tool for Java.

Answer (score 3):

[Typemock Racer](http://docs.typemock.com/racer/##RacerHelp.chm/html/4744c118-5744-4885-a3d0-8433d5f8ccc7.htm) might be what you're looking for but I haven't used it - I just remembered something about deadlocks :)

Or this: [Deadlock Detector](http://www.lockexplorer.com/)

Answer (score 2):

This [announcement](http://research.microsoft.com/projects/CHESS/) from Microsoft Research sounds like they have a tool that does exactly what I want. Unfortunately there's no .net version yet, but there is one planned. To quote the site:

> CHESS is an automated tool for finding
>   errors in multithreaded software by
>   systematic exploration of thread
>   schedules. It finds errors, such as
>   data-races, deadlocks, hangs, and
>   data-corruption induced access
>   violations, that are extremely hard to
>   find with current testing tools. Once
>   CHESS locates an error, it provides a
>   fully repeatable execution of the
>   program leading to the error, thus
>   greatly aiding the debugging process.
>   In addition, CHESS provides a valuable
>   and novel notion of test coverage
>   suitable for multithreaded programs.
>   CHESS can use existing concurrent test
>   cases and is therefore easy to deploy.
>   Both developers and testers should
>   find CHESS useful.

Comment: Microsoft's tool is not available yet (and might be for some time).

Comment: It's available now, but not for VS2010 or VS2012 yet.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen [Debug Inspector](http://www.debuginspector.com) (www.debuginspector.com) ?

It does managed and unmanaged deadlocks and covers both WaitForSingleObject and WaitForMultipleObjects and works for XP and Vista

Answer (score 1):

There’s a great windbg extension, written by Steve Johnson, called sosex which has a deadlock finding command. You can find it at http://www.stevestechspot.com/downloads/sosex_32.zip and you can read more about it
here: http://www.stevestechspot.com/SOSEXANewDebuggingExtensionForManagedCode.aspx
and here: http://www.stevestechspot.com/SOSEXUpdatedV11Available.aspx.

Comment: It just finds runtime deadlocks which are simple to find anyway; because if you have one your program stops completely and you just have a look at all stacks.