# .NET multithreading and unit testing

Tags: .net, multithreading, unit-testing

How I could use unit testing for catching multithreading bugs in my .NET applications? Is there any frameworks or libraries?

Comment: Try this: ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12159/how-should-i-unit-test-threaded-code or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200402/what-tools-exist-for-testing-multithreaded-net-code or .... Read the rules and FAQ before asking

Comment: Your link are four years old! May be something new thing to get ready to know?!

Answer (score 3):

You could try using CHESS:

[CHESS: Find and Reproduce Heisenbugs in Concurrent Programs](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/chess/):

> CHESS is a tool for finding and reproducing Heisenbugs in concurrent
>   programs. CHESS repeatedly runs a concurrent test ensuring that every
>   run takes a different interleaving. If an interleaving results in an
>   error, CHESS can reproduce the interleaving for improved debugging.
>   CHESS is available for both managed and native programs.

Comment: I see it, but it has version number only 0.1 and last update was at 2009... The project has been dead?

Comment: Not sure when it was last updated: a colleague has used it with some good results.

Comment: So, for example, you can't use visual studio 2010 with it. Only visual studio 2008...

Comment: Yes, that's true. But it is easy to have two solutions, one for 2008 and one for 2010 (TFS supports this). And if it were to find subtle bugs that might remain hidden for months (or years), then the effort would be worthwhile.